# Как при получении задания печати на принтер издавать звук?

Tags: java, windows, принтер

Из производственной необходимости возникла идея написать программу, которая издавала бы звук в том случае, если на общий в организации принтер приходит задание на печать с того компьютера к которому он подключен. Пишу на java. Я совсем начинающий поэтому даже догадываться не берусь как это реализовать ...

Comment: А так то Вам надо собирать со всех печатающих устройств события по SNTP, парсить их определяя выполненные и автору задания посылать гудок. (Интересно куда будет ломиться за результатом автор задания если больше одного принтера.) Правда я не знаю как к этому решению прикручивать яву :(

Comment: Насколько я знаю, спикер есть в большинстве материнок, для подачи звуковых сигналов об ошибках. Можно его использовать.

Comment: @learp уже давно нет.

Comment: Немного не в тему, но просветите, а то может я отстал. Как тогда сообщить об ошибках в POST(Power-On Self-Test)?

Comment: Дело в том что на этот принтер много приходит всего и надо понимать когда это печатает оператор машины а когда кто то еще. Есть колонки. Да и прикрутить проигрывание звука я смогу. А вот как понять с какого компьютера на этот принтер пришло задание?

Comment: @learp ну у нас для этого есть динамик который цепляют на разъем на материнке для динамика и слушают. иначе - никак :( я не знаю почему так стали делать и как теперь слушать ошибки, но действительность именно такова :(

Comment: @LvovConstantin веб интерфейс же есть у принтера? он отображает задания и кто их послал. либо вытягивать оттуда, либо забирать по SNTP, как я уже писал.

Comment: Не понятно, как организована печать с помощью принт-сервера (на базе Windows) или это отдельное устройство с выделенным адресом в сети?

Comment: Честно говоря я не знаю. Могу сказать только что даже ip так и не смог найти этого принтера. Ни в настройках принтера ни при попытке пингануть его по имени. В настройках пусто пинг не нашел узел. На распечатке пробной страницы Среда: windows nt x86 на компьютере стоит 10_ая виндовс

Comment: В настройках порта принтера нужно посмотреть соединение. Наконец проверить физическое подключение к ПК, например, по USB соединению! Как выявите каналы связи, или получите сведения об прошивке сетевого принтера, или укажите модель устройства, тогда можно будет говорить предметно.